# Update/Edit an Entry in C# CRUD Operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, crud

I am trying to edit a `RoleName` in my `Roles` table. Everything is working except I am getting errors that there is no definition for the `Entry` and the `SaveChanges` methods. I have `using` statements for both `System.Data.Entity` and `EntityFramework` so I am not sure what the issue is. I'm pretty sure that I have all the correct packages and references.

```
//Get Edit
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Roles model)
{
    return View(); 
}

//Put Edit
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Comtrex_ICU.Models.Roles model, int RoleId, 
    Roles RoleName)
{
    try
    {
        Roles db = new Roles();

        db.Entry(RoleName).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("RolesIndex");
    }
    catch 
    { 
        return View(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the definition of Roles class. It seems to that compiler was unable to find two methods in Roles class: Entry and SaveChanges

Comment: Why does your POST Edit signature have two instances of Roles being passed into it? What is `Roles RoleName` and how is it being resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As you don't appear to be calling them from a repository, `Entry` and `SaveChanges` are methods belonging to your EntityFramework Entities.

You're trying to call them from an instance of `Roles`.

You need to instantiate your Entities as `db`.

Instead of the following:

```
Roles db = new Roles();
```

You should do this (where Entities is the name you've given your entities):

```
Entities db = new Entities();
```

You can now find the Role you want to edit by using `Find`:

```
var editRole = db.Roles.Find(RoleId);
```

Then you need to map your edited properties and then make your update.

You should instantiate your entities in the constructor of either the Controller or a service repository rather than each time you need it, but the example above should point you in the right direction.